# Ionic 4 + Net Core 2.3 Route API calls

Tags: c#, ionic-framework, asp.net-core, angular-ui-router

I'm encountering a problem that I can't find anything like in the forums.

My frontend (Ionic 4) works fine but when I try to call the Web API (Net Core 2.2) through a url like http://localhost:50361/api/companies/getcompaniessimplelist it never reachs th backend.

I guess this is a route problem. Anyway here goes all the files I think are neccessary to find a solution. By the way, I'm using VS Code:

**launch.json**

```
{
            "name": ".NET Core Launch Chrome (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/TavoraApp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start \"\" \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\" ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        }
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule' },
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
    { path: 'manage', loadChildren: './pages/manage/manage.module#ManagePageModule' },
    { path: 'tools', loadChildren: './pages/tools/tools.module#ToolsPageModule' },
    { path: 'accounting', loadChildren: './pages/accounting/accounting.module#AccountingPageModule' },
    { path: 'contracts', loadChildren: './pages/contracts/contracts.module#ContractsPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using TavoraApp.Extensions;
using TavoraCore;

namespace TavoraApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly Type[] profileTypes =
        {
            typeof(TavoraMapper.Profiles.Companies.CompanySimpleMapper)
        };

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddJsonFormatters()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddAutoMapper(profileTypes);

            services.ConfigureCors();

            services.ConfigureAuthentication();

            services.AddDbContext<TavoraContext>
                (options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    mysqlOptions =>
                    {
                        mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 16), ServerType.MySql);
                        mysqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly("TavoraCore");
                    }));

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                //if (Regex.IsMatch(Configuration["ASPNETCORE_URLS"], @"https?://localhost[:/]")) // is local
                //{
                //    string tsDefinitionsPath = "./ClientApp/src/app/models/";
                //    string tsDefinitionsFullPath = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, tsDefinitionsPath);

                //    app.GenerateTypeScriptInterfaces(tsDefinitionsFullPath);

                //    app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseCors("Cors");
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "api",
                    template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```